# Reset struct values in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Looks like this question has been asked a few times but I can't seem to get it working based on existing answers and guidance.

Here's the code:

```
#include <atomic>

class X
{
  public:
    X();
    ~X();
    void alpha();
  private:
    struct A {
      bool m;
      std::atomic<bool> n;
      bool fish();
    };
    A aval_;
};

X::X() : aval_() {}
X::~X() {}

bool X::A::fish() {
  return true;
}

void X::alpha() {
  aval_.m = false;
  aval_ = {};
}
```

> Object of type 'X::A' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted

Should I be overriding something? I am not generally a C++ programmer so feel free to point me to resources where I can learn more.

EDIT: Updated the source code to include `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: After fixing obvious typos and adding missing declarations the code [compiles for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LBYLve). `= {}` normally works, but in your actual code you probably have some non-copyable/non-movable members in your class which make it non-copyable/non-movable. We can't tell you more without a [mcve]. Also a complete error message would help too.

Comment: Hmm; unfortunately I can't really share any code. But let me make sense of things here. Thank you for your prompt and helpful response.

Comment: I'm surprised your compiler didn't say anything about the ill-formed constructor of `X`. Or that you hadn't declared `X()` and `void alpha()` before defining them outside the `class`. Weird... Btw, making the corrections mentioned by @HolyBlackCat, the code works fine in `g++`, `clang` and `vc++`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have updated the example. It seems there is an issue when there are atomic member variables.

Comment: The [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) confirms that atomics can't be copied or moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `std::atomic` does not have a default copy-constructor. Try the following code:

```
std::atomic<bool> v1(false);
std::atomic<bool> v2  = v1;
```

The errors you should get are:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::atomic<bool>'
    std::atomic<bool> n2  = n1;
                      ^     ~~
note: copy constructor of 'atomic<bool>' is implicitly deleted because base class '__atomic_base<bool>' has a deleted copy constructor

note: '__atomic_base' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    __atomic_base(const __atomic_base&) = delete;
```

If the sole purpose of this is to reset the members of `A`, then simply create a reset function `void reset()` and reset the members to their initial values.

```
void reset()
{
    m = false;
    n = false;
}
```

and then in `void alpha()` do:

```
void alpha()
{
    aval.m = false;
    aval.reset();
}
```

The above is *Plan A*. As *Plan B*, you can use a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr`) to hold `aval`. Then you can simply `reset` the pointer.

So instead of using the stack:

```
A aval;
```

You use the heap:

```
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<A> aval;

public:
    X() : aval(std::make_unique<A>())
    {;}

    void alpha()
    {
        aval->m = false;
        aval.reset(new A());
    }
```

I personally like the first approach. Consider the fact that, regardless of its' name "constructor", a constructor constructs nothing. All it does is initialize the members of the class. That's exactly what the `reset()` does, and you use the stack.